# Force parallax section to extend to bottom of page

Tags: javascript

I have a one-page parallax website - I am trying to force each parallax section to extend to the bottom of the page so you can't see the next section unless you click on it - is there a simple way of doing this?

At the moment I put the following code in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imageFit = function() {
   windowHeight = $(window).height();
   $('.parallax-section').css('min-height', windowHeight).refresh();
};
</script>
```

And the following in CSS

```
.parallax-section {
    height: 100%;
    clear: both !important;
    }

.min-height {
    min-height: 100%; 
    }
```

But it doesn't extend... Any idea what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you can use the newer `vh` units which are relative to browser height rather than content, though your javascript should work:

```
.parallax-section {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```